# Making non-default port accesible on public network in EC2 AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to use my EC2 instance on public IP for multiple applications(as a staging server). By default, port 80(or 443 for https) is publicly accessible for HTTP. But, I want to use other ports as well. For example,
http://my-aws-public-url.com:4050

I have already provided access to port 4050 using security group, but it is still not working. Can you please provide me what I am missing.

Comment: Is some service or process listening on port 4050 on your EC2 instance ? Merely adding a rule for port 4050 in security group isn’t going to do anything.

Comment: Yes, web application is hosted on the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a port publicly accessible, you need to follow all the below steps.

1. Add custom rule in the security group to allow the custom port, i.e, 4050 in the example above.
   [image]
2. Add an elastic IP to the EC2 instance
3. Your instance should be publicly accessible(defined using VPC, network ACL and subnet). This step can be verified if the default port is publicly accessbile.
4. Lastly, the port should be enabled in windows firewall(Go to windows firewall -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule -> Port -> Select TCP and specify local port(e.g. 4050)).
   [image]